# How can I avoid of using same iterator while moving to another-if statement in same loop?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use `continue;` but looks like - incorrect;
Every 3 times I have same "i" value. How can I skip iterator when running `if(currentShiftCD != 3 & currentShiftAB == 3)` and `if(currentShiftDC != 3 & currentShiftBA == 3)` for the first time after switching bools `firsThreeDays` and `secondThreeDays`

I want output to startlike: 1,2,3,4,5,6..19 but have with same values:

[image]

```
 for (int i = 1; i <20; i++)
        {
            if (firstThreeDays)
            {

                if (currentShiftAB != 3)
                {
                    currentShiftAB++;
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " A-B");
                }
                if (currentShiftCD != 3 & currentShiftAB == 3)
                {
                    currentShiftCD++;                       
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " C-D");
                }

                if (currentShiftAB == 3 & currentShiftCD == 3)
                  {
                      firstThreeDays = false;
                      secondThreeDays = true;
                      currentShiftAB = 0;
                      currentShiftCD = 0;
                      continue;
                  }
            }

            if (secondThreeDays)
            {
                if (currentShiftBA != 3)
                {
                    currentShiftBA++;
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " B-A");
                }
                if (currentShiftDC != 3 & currentShiftBA == 3)
                {
                    currentShiftDC++;        
                    Console.WriteLine(i + " D-C");
                }

                if (currentShiftBA == 3 & currentShiftDC == 3)
                {
                    secondThreeDays = false;
                    firstThreeDays = true;
                    currentShiftBA = 0;
                    currentShiftDC = 0;
                    continue;
                }

            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Which `continue` is incorrect? What happens? What do you want instead?

Comment: What is *underlying problem* you are trying to solve? What do all `A-B`, `C-D` stand for, please?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `&` instead of `&&`

Comment: Just run debugger and go through code step by step.

Comment: I think you need to use **else if** instead of one if after the other, else the loop can enter into each if

Comment: @Sinatr I updated post with screenshot

Comment: Could you, please, put down the *desired* behaviour/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the sequencing of your first two if statements, inside the firstThreeDays as well as secondThreeDays. Use `if, else-if, else-if` construct.

```
// Suppose your loop has executed once. Now, currentShiftAB is 2.

if (currentShiftAB != 3) // currentShiftAB is not 3.It enters this if.
{
    currentShiftAB++;     // currentshiftAB is now 3.
    Console.WriteLine(i + " A-B"); //It prints 3 A-B
}

// Now, currentShiftAB is 3 but currentShiftCD is not 3. 
// your code enters this if condition as well at the same time.
// That's why you are getting duplicate output for i=3. 
if (currentShiftCD != 3 & currentShiftAB == 3)
{
    currentShiftCD++;                       
    Console.WriteLine(i + " C-D");
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right... if I put at the end of the first one  - if(currentShiftAB == 3){ continue;} , I have correct output.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use `continue` to "solve" your problem just use the `else` clause with your first `if`

```
for (int i = 1; i <20; i++)
{
    if (firstThreeDays)
    {

        if (currentShiftAB != 3)
        {
            currentShiftAB++;
            Console.WriteLine(i + " A-B");
        }

        if (currentShiftCD != 3 & currentShiftAB == 3)
        {
            currentShiftCD++;                       
            Console.WriteLine(i + " C-D");
        }
        if (currentShiftAB == 3 & currentShiftCD == 3)
        {
            firstThreeDays = false;
            secondThreeDays = true;
            currentShiftAB = 0;
            currentShiftCD = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (secondThreeDays)
    {
        if (currentShiftBA != 3)
        {
            currentShiftBA++;
            Console.WriteLine(i + " B-A");
        }

        if (currentShiftDC != 3 & currentShiftBA == 3)
        {
            currentShiftDC++;        
            Console.WriteLine(i + " D-C");
        }

        if (currentShiftBA == 3 & currentShiftDC == 3)
        {
            secondThreeDays = false;
            firstThreeDays = true;
            currentShiftBA = 0;
            currentShiftDC = 0;
        }
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

This will guarantee that the `if (secondThreeDays)` block doesn't get run in the same iteration as the `if (firstThreeDays)` block.